# Cannot access resources in JAR file (media and images)

Tags: java, windows, jar, resources, manifest

Finished a program and exported it as a JAR artifact, only to realise my JAR file is unable to access the resources folder in my project. I am aware there are many questions LIKE THIS on this site, however none seem helpful for my topics.

```
public class Song {

String name;
String bip;
Media hit;

public Song(String name){
    this.name = name;
    bip = "resources/" + name + ".mp3";
    hit = new Media(Paths.get(bip).toUri().toString());
}

public Media getHit(){
    return hit;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}
}
```

This is my class above and I wish to access the songs from the resources folder.

Comment: `Song.class.getResouce(path)`?

Comment: Unfortunately does not work